# What is "delayed environment variable expansion"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there someone to explain exactly what is `delayed environment variable expansion` in simple terms or point to a post that can understand. Here is my questions

- What can't I achieve without this
- In which practical situations uses this
- Any alternative

Comment: [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) always is a good starting point. Also [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cmd]+delayed+expansion) has a lot of info.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696734/how-to-put-variable-value-inside-another-variable-name-in-batch

Comment: I posted this explanation a long time ago. It explains it in a manner you will understand. http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=985

Comment: A very simple example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405906/batch-file-add-remove-hosts-file-entries-syntax-error/9407130#9407130)

Comment: Last but not least opening a command prompt window, entering `set /?` or `help set` and reading all output help text helps also to understand delayed variable expansion as explained on two small examples, an __IF__ and a __FOR__ example.

Comment: Please also note that `DOS` is the OS from the 1980/1990s, and I don't think you are using that.

Answer (score 1):

**%Var%** is expanded when a line is read. As lines can have multiple commands, `!var!` is expanded when used. In *MS-DOS* `!var!` (accessed in script by `%!var!%`) is a legal variable name so you have to turn on a special mode to access. This is so *MS-DOS* batch files can run in *CMD* without editing.